# Error : Subscript value 9 not valid. Must be between 0 and 8

Tags: variables, repeat, visualforce

This is my vf page, I am getting 9 records in `BadgeController` in `conList`, i.e. `conList[0]` to `conList[8]`.

I am using variables `first` and `second` as a subscript to List.

I am incrementing value of variable by 2 in each apex:repeat, it works fine from 0 to 2.

But when variable become 9 it is showing error like:

> Subscript value 9 not valid. Must be between 0 and 8 .

How to prevent variable from incrementing?

how to break the execution of code in if .. else condition?

```
<apex:page standardController="Event__c" extensions="BadgeController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf">

<html>
<head>
</head>
<center>

<apex:variable var="first" value="{!0}" id="id3"/>
<apex:variable var="second" value="{!1}" id="id4"/>

<apex:repeat value="{!conList}" >

<apex:variable var="first" value="{!first+ 2}" id="id1"/>
<apex:variable var="second" value="{!second+ 2}" id="id2"/>



<table><tr><td>

<table BORDER="2" RULES="NONE" FRAME="BOX">
<tr>
<td>
<table height="100px" width="300px" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="30">

<tr>
<td><center><apex:outputField value="{!conList[first].AccountContact__r.FirstName}"/></center></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>

</tr>

</table></td>

<td></td>
<td>

<table BORDER="2" RULES="NONE" FRAME="BOX">
<tr>
<td>
<table height="100px" width="300px" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="30">


<tr>
<td><center><apex:outputField value="{!conList[second].AccountContact__r.FirstName}"/></center></td>
</tr>


</table>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
</td></tr></table> <br></br><br></br>

</apex:repeat>
</center>
</html>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but it sounds like you simply want to display alternating values in a list. This is a job for Apex (or perhaps JavaScript if you really don't want to code any Apex, though you should get to know Apex if you plan to remain on Force.com for a while). In Apex you can do whatever you like with lists and display whatever you need to display *without* tightly coupling your presentation with your business logic. From the Visualforce Developer's Guide:

> Note: apex:variable does not support reassignment inside of an
>   iteration component, such as apex:dataTable or apex:repeat. The
>   result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the apex:variable as a
>   counter, is unsupported and undefined.

So here's an Apex sample that creates two lists of alternating elements for Visualforce to display:

```
public with sharing class Sample 
{
    public List<Contact> conListOne {get; private set;}
    public List<Contact> conListTwo {get; private set;}

    public Sample()
    {
        conListOne = new List<Contact>();
        conListTwo = new List<Contact>();

        Contact[] tmpConList = [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
        Integer i = 0;
        while(i < tmpConList.size())
        {
            conListOne.add(tmpConList[i]);
            if((i + 1) < tmpConList.size())
            {
                conListTwo.add(tmpConList[i+1]);
            }
            i += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can display two different lists in Visualforce that have even/odd row numbers from your original SOQL:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conListOne}" var="item">
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conListTwo}" var="item">
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Or just modify the Apex to produce a single list with whatever row order you wish and display that.

Hope that helps.